# Calling an arraylist from another class

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

here is my code for the arraylist class;
package Restaurant;

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;



    public class Controlclass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Create ArrayList for foodItems subclasses
            ArrayList<Mains> MainsList = new ArrayList<Mains>();
    //add items to the MainsList
            Mains  CurriedFriedRice = new Mains (" Curried fried rice ", 4.00, " Yummy curried fried rice " , 500);
            Mains  LambChopsWithCarrotPuree = new Mains (" Lamb chops with carrot puree ", 6.00, " Delicious Lamb chops with carrot puree " , 580);
            Mains  PadThaiNoodles = new Mains (" Pad Thai noodles ", 5.00, " Amazing thai noodles " , 480);
            Mains  SalmonAndAsparagusFajitas = new Mains (" Salmon and asparagus fajitas ", 4.90, " Fajita you will always come back for " , 450);


    MainsList.add(CurriedFriedRice);
            MainsList.add(LambChopsWithCarrotPuree);
            MainsList.add(PadThaiNoodles);
            MainsList.add(SalmonAndAsparagusFajitas);


    for (Mains mains: MainsList){
                System.out.println(mains);
            }
```

and this is the GUI class i need to use these arraylists in;

```
*

public class TheFoodLoversLounge {
    private final GridLayout layout; // layout of this frame
    private JFrame frame;
    private final JPanel buttonbar;
    private final JPanel combobar;
    private final JPanel receiptbar;
private final JComboBox<String> mainsc; 
public class TheFoodLoversLounge {
    private final GridLayout layout; // layout of this frame
    private JFrame frame;
    private final JPanel buttonbar;
    private final JPanel combobar;
    private final JPanel receiptbar;
    private final JComboBox<String> starters; 
    private final JComboBox<String> mainsc; 
    private final JComboBox<String> dessert; 
    private final JButton getTotalPrice;
    private final JLabel l2;
    private final JLabel l3;
    private final JLabel l4;
    private final JLabel l5;
    private final JLabel l6;
    private final JLabel l7;
    private final JLabel l8;
    private final JLabel l9;
    private final JLabel l10;
    private final JLabel r1;
    private final JLabel r2;
    private final JLabel r3;
    private final JLabel r4;
    private final JLabel r5;
    private final JLabel r6;
    private final JLabel r7;
    private final JLabel r8;
    private final JLabel r9;
    private Controlclass control;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TheFoodLoversLounge window = new TheFoodLoversLounge();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TheFoodLoversLounge() {
        MAXTABLES=10;
        MAXDINERS=10;
        initialize();
        control = new Controlclass();
        layout = new GridLayout(0,1,0,5);
        starters=new JComboBox<>(); 
        mainsc=new JComboBox<>(); 
        dessert=new JComboBox<>(); 

        for (Starters starterI: control.StarterList){
            starters.addItem(starterI.toString());
        }
        starters.setMaximumRowCount(5);
        for (Mains mainsI: control.MainsList){
            mainsc.addItem(mainsI.toString());
        }
        mainsc.setMaximumRowCount(5);
        for (Dessert dessertI: control.DessertList){
            dessert.addItem(dessertI.toString());
        }
buttonbar= new JPanel(layout);
        buttonbar.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        buttonbar.add(getTotalPrice); buttonbar.add(l10);
combobar= new JPanel(layout);
        combobar.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        combobar.add(l1); combobar.add(starters);
        combobar.add(l2); combobar.add(mainsc);
        combobar.add(l4); combobar.add(dessert);
private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(768, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
private class TheListener implements ActionListener
    {
        // process text field events
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        { 
            String string = "";
            double arr [];
            Orders ord = new Orders();
            if (event.getSource() ==getTotalPrice){
                ord.diners= Integer.parseInt((String) diners.getItemAt(diners.getSelectedIndex()));
                ord.tableno=Integer.parseInt((String) tableno.getItemAt(tableno.getSelectedIndex()));
                ord.item[0]=starters.getItemAt(starters.getSelectedIndex());
                // ord.qty[1]=
                        ord.rate[0]=control.StarterList.get(starters.getSelectedIndex()).price;
                        ord.item[1]=mainsc.getItemAt(mainsc.getSelectedIndex());
                        // ord.qty[2]=
                        ord.rate[1]=control.MainsList.get(mainsc.getSelectedIndex()).price;
                        ord.item[2]=dessert.getItemAt(dessert.getSelectedIndex());
                        // ord.qty[3]=
                        ord.rate[2]=control.DessertList.get(dessert.getSelectedIndex()).price;
}
        }}}
```

*
Can everyone ignore the syntax errors please because its not full code and i just want to focus on the arraylist because everytime i try to compile it gives me the following error while the actual code is syntactically correct. 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

```
StarterList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    MainsList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    DessertList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    DrinksList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    FishList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    StarterList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    MainsList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    DessertList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    FishList cannot be resolved or is not a field
    DrinksList cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at Restaurant.TheFoodLoversLounge.<init>(TheFoodLoversLounge.java:121)
    at Restaurant.TheFoodLoversLounge$1.run(TheFoodLoversLounge.java:91)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

these are the errors that i get. I dont know how to fix these. can anyone help me with them please. The reason for not putting the full code up is as its my project and i cant risk it. So a fix from you guys would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the compiler gives errors, your code is not syntactically correct. If it was, you wouldn't get errors. Fix the errors, respect the Java naming conventions, and for your own sanity, choose better variable names than l3 or r6.

Comment: One thing that I would recommend first is to rename all of your lists to start with lowercase letter. Uppercase starting names are typically used in classes so that makes things very confusing. It also looks as though you just don't even define any of those lists in Controlclass

Comment: Try re-constructing your issue in a very small (new) example project. Remove everything that may be unrelated, like GUI elements, unnecessary methods, etc. Use only one list, and try to access it for a very basic GUI application. This is called an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and can often help you find your problem yourself. If not, post _that_ MVCE as a question. As the question currently is, it is unsalvageable.

Comment: actually i am going to change the naming of everything once it gets fixed but it would compile in java but not in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Do not define your lists in `main` method. Define them as members and initialize them in constructor. Then write getter methods for each list.

```
public class Controlclass {
   private ArrayList<Mains> MainsList;

   public ControlClass() {
       MainsList = new ArrayList<Mains>()
   }

   public ArrayList<Mains> getMainsList() {
        return MainsList;
   }
}
```

Finally, use the getter methods to reach the lists.

```
for (Mains mainsI: control.getMainsList()){
```

Comment: makes sense. i'll try doing this. tnxx

Answer (score 1):

`Controlclass` doesn't provide any kind of access to any of the `ArrayList`s you defined within the `main` method (and there is a huge hint to your problem).

Start by defining instance fields in your `Controlclass` and the provide `public` getters to allow them access to those fields (through a method you can control - for example, you could return immutable lists or copy the list before returning it)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Controlclass {

        private List<...> starterList;
        private List<...> mainsList;
        private List<...> dessertList;
        private List<...> drinksList;
        private List<...> fishList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controlclass controlClass = new Controlclass();
    }

    public Controlclass() {
        starterList = new ArrayList<>(25);
        mainsList = new ArrayList<>(25);
        dessertList = new ArrayList<>(25);
        drinksList = new ArrayList<>(25);
        fishList = new ArrayList<>(25);

        // Populate the values...
    }

    public List<...> getStarterList() {
        return starterList;
    }

    public List<...> getMainsList() {
        return mainsList;
    }

    public List<...> getDessertList() {
        return dessertList;
    }

    public List<...> getDrinksList() {
        return drinksList;
    }

    public List<...> getFishList() {
        return fishList;
    }
}
```

*(ps You will need to replace `<...>` with the appropriate generics, I didn't really want to dig through all your code to figure it out)*

Next pass an instance of the `Controlclass` to your other classes

```
public class TheFoodLoversLounge {
    //...
    private Controlclass control;

    public TheFoodLoversLounge(Controlclass control) {
        this.control = control
        //...
```

Finally, make use of the properties of the `Controlclass`

```
for (Starters starterI: control.getStarterList()) {
    starters.addItem(starterI.toString());
}
```

(and make your mind which is you main entry point for the program, having two `main` methods is going to be very confusing)

Comment: I think rdonuk got in first with the same idea, while an upvote would be nice, they deserve the credit for answering the question (IMHO)